# Is MAX, MIN, SUM SQL command standard accross diffrent RDBMS

Tags: php, sql, aggregate-functions, rdbms, rdbms-agnostic

I only have MySQL installed right now but will these work fine when run in PgSQL, MS SQL, etc.?

```
SELECT MAX(field) as max_field FROM table
SELECT MIN(field) as max_field FROM table
SELECT SUM(field) as max_field FROM table
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check for yourself, but aggregate functions are common across most, if not all, RDBMS:

- [H2 aggregate functions](http://www.h2database.com/html/functions.html)
- [Oracle aggregate functions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10592/functions003.htm)
- [PostgreSQL aggregate functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/functions-aggregate.html)
- [SQL Server aggregate functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173454.aspx)

You get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they work well in every database.

```
SELECT AVG(field) as max_field FROM table -- Work fine too
```

Answer (score 0):

*All* *SQL RDBMSes are designed to be used with the SQL language. ALL of them. That's why they're called *SQL RDBMSes. Aggregate functions are part of standard SQL, and therefore usable wherever SQL is usable.

Comment: I believe the question was whether the aggregate functions were part of standard sql or were vendor specific